# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting the NoSuchmethodError while hitting the endpoints from the postman. I have recently migrated from spring 1.15 to 2.5.8.

Here are my spring versions.
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.8'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'

Any thoughts on fixing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities & resolution !

1. Check if that method is available under the class under which it is throwing error!  You can check it from under Maven dependencies by expanding that particular library.
2. Check if your `pom.xml` does not contain same dependency declarations (with same or different versions)
3. Delete the redundant dependency from classpath to make sure only one exist. Most likely, `NoSuchMethodError` appears when there is more than 1 same dependency on classpath and and older version (or first encountered) is picked up !

***Check if these articles help***

[How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

[How to resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233192/how-to-resolve-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)

[How to get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798767/how-to-get-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)